# switch condtion going on first case on int 0

Tags: php, variables, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I have code something like this:

```
function someFunction($myKey){
  switch($myKey){
     case 'equals':
       $condition = '=';
       break;
     case 'notequals':
       $condition = '!=';
       break;
     default:
        $condition = 'like';
        break;
  }
  return $condition;
}
echo someFunction(1);        // output 'like' good 
echo someFunction('equals'); // output '=' also good 
echo someFunction(0);        // but here output '=' why ?
echo someFunction(true);     // and here also '=' why ?
```

As I commented, why `0` and `true` goes to first case instead of default?

Although I fix that just cast `$myKey` to string before switch condition 
but I am curious what I did wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [PHP `switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) page you can see that it uses [Loose Comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose).

- Comparison with integer `0` casts string `equals` to integer `0`
- Comparison with boolean `true` casts  string `equals` to boolean `true`

Since you are comparing strings, cast the argument to a string with `(string)` or `strval()`:

```
function someFunction($myKey){
    switch((string)$myKey){
     case 'equals':
       $condition = '=';
       break;
     case 'notequals':
       $condition = '!=';
       break;
     default:
        $condition = 'like';
        break;
  }
  return $condition;
}
```

Comment: Wow Buddy Thanks For explanation.